# Http PATCH with Spring Android

Tags: android, spring, http

I am working against an API using Spring-Android but when I tried to do a PATCH I noticed there is no corresponding method in [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). 
The Docs advise me to use the exchange or execute but I have a hard time understanding how.
Also PATCH does not seem to be included in the Spring-Android 1.0.1 HttpMethod.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the code explain it best:

If you have understand what the method `RestTemplage.postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)` does, then have a look at the way how it is implemented.

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String url, Object request,
                    Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
                    throws RestClientException {

    HttpEntityRequestCallback requestCallback = 
                                  new HttpEntityRequestCallback(request, responseType);
    ResponseEntityResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor =
                                  new ResponseEntityResponseExtractor<T>(responseType);
    return execute(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor, uriVariables);
}
```

I hope you understand how you can map this example to other Http Methods.

*If you have not added the spring code to your IDE, you can have a look this [url for the RestTemplate code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java?format=ok)*

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it better now, but the execute method takes an HttpPost as an argument and SpringAndroid seems to lack PATCH. Even though I can see that it's added to the spring source on github.

Comment: @Qw4z1 Do you mean HttpMethod.POST?  There is also a HttpMethod.PATCH!

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/api/ If you look at the javadocs for Spring Android, you will see that there is no PATCH for version 1.0.x and since I am using 1.0.1 I have no PATCH in my HttpMethod.

Comment: Otherwise I would have gone with your solution. Now I just use PUT until PATCH is supported.